# How to get the userID from a custom ASP.Net Membership Provider w/ non-unique usernames?

Tags: asp.net-membership

I've created a custom asp.net membership provider that authenticates against a legacy database. The problem I'm running into to is how to handle users that have same username.

I've repeatedly tried convincing my boss that a username should be unique but this has been to no avail.

**Update**:
It does seem to be fundamental flaw with the authentication system, but how do I convince my boss that he needs to update his Powerbuilder code? I've been trying for nearly 2 years now and he thinks a unique (username,password) is good enough. I also want to store the passwords in a unidirectional hash instead of plaintext.

Comment: You need some sort of unique identifier. What logic are you using to differentiate between two "Aplato"s? Just the password? If they both change their password to '123456', either they become the same user or you have to give an error message that says "Someone else with this exact same username has that password already. Now that you know that, please don't log in as them."

Comment: Agreed, this is a problem that transcends the requirements of ASP.NET membership

Comment: What problem is the unique usernames causing you, exactly?

Comment: The passwords in plain text should be enough!

Answer (score 1):

Something has to be unique. The user id is a guid which is unique, I have email address as unique so you can use that.

Comment: Email address is nullable, non-unique, and may contain more than one address.